# How do I write predicate instance methods with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pug

A semi-noob node guy here. In my jade templates ... I'd really love to be able to have this interface:

```
if currentUser.isMemberOfGroup(name)
  -// dosomething
```

However, determining a user's membership involves interfacing with mongoose ... which is always an async'd affair. Using mongoose docs as an example I would WANT to write something along these lines (pardon me, this is written in coffee):

```
userSchema.methods.isMemberOfGroup = (name) ->
  Club.findOne(name: name).populate({
    path: 'members',
    model: 'User',
    match: { _id: @id }
  }).exec (err, club) ->
    club.members.length > 0
```

Is there a way I can get this method to return a bool instead of the immediate return from the exec function? What is the "right" way to design such an interface?

Here's the rest of the Club model:

```
clubSchema = Mongoose.Schema
  name: String
  hashTag: String
  members: [{ type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
```

Comment: I'd recommend fetching that information in your route as parallel as you can with your other tasks ([flow control libraries](https://github.com/caolan/async) makes this really easy) and then adding the result to your locals. Or, you can use javascript on the front end to go fetch this information async and update the page when completed (a.k.a add a dedicated async route to provide this information). Really, writing blocking code (synchronous) in the jade render process would be the same as waiting in the controller logic for this information.

Comment: Also, if you're just looking for the Clubs which have the user _id in its members, you can get all the clubs the user is part of like this with mongoose: `Club.find { members : user._id }, 'name', (err, clubs)->`

Comment: Tyler, thanks so much for the feedback. Yeah, setting it in the route seems to be the next best option ... I'm just less thrilled about setting a bunch of locals rather than just passing a single object. I prefer the Rails paradigm whereby I don't have to bake EVERY single datapoint before I pass the vars off to the view ... but I will just have to adapt.

Comment: No problem Cody. I completely understand your point of view. To clean things up, I sometime wrap the locals from the route in a "viewModel" object (i.e `res.locals.viewModel = { userMemberOf : clubs, user : user }`), just to organize a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Does Jade support async functions (it seems it doesn't https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/641)? If not, you'll have to load the value before you render your template.

This is in fact generally a good practice as it allows separation of concerns (the view should not know about the database). By the way, if you need to do a lot of async conditional logic have a look at https://github.com/olalonde/boolasync (a module I wrote). Also, if you need to do multiple database calls, I strongly recommend you use async.series or async.parallel to make your code more readable (don't go nest more than a few levels deep).